# How to avoid this Abort trap: 6 error in C

Tags: c

I try to write a function converting decimal number to hexadecimal and binary number. However, I get this `Abort trap: 6` when my input is larger than 1023. I think this might be that I didn't allocate enough memory to my list?

```
void printHexadecimalForm(int X)
//Purpose: Print parameter X in hexadecimal form
//Output: Hexadecimal representation of X directly printed
//Assumption: X is non-negative (i.e. >= 0)
{
    int ans[100];
    int i = 0;
    char HEX[16] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    //[TODO] CHANGE this to your solution.
    for (i = 0; X > 0; i++)
    {
        ans[i] = X % 16;
        X = X / 16;
    }
    //printf("Binary form coming soon!\n");
    for (int n = i - 1; n >= 0; n--)
    {
        printf("%c", HEX[ans[n]]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main(void)
{
    int X;

    printf("Enter X: ");
    scanf("%d", &X);

    //print X in hexadecimal form
    printHexadecimalForm(X);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that the whole file, or are there `#include` lines at the top?

Comment: I tried running this code on online compilers, the code is giving correct answers to me

Comment: Your code looks totally ok assuming that you did include <stdio.h>

Comment: It’s important to check the return value of `scanf`. `scanf` returns the number of values it read successfully; compare that to the number of values you expected (in this case, one) to see whether it failed. `if (scanf("%d", &X) != 1) { puts("Couldn't read a number."); return 1; }`

Comment: Hi all, i just realise i didn't include the whole file, ill update now, sorry guys

Comment: Am i not allowed to edit my own question?

Comment: which compiler did you use?

Comment: You are allowed to edit your own question; there should be a small “edit” link in grey below the question but above these comments (near “share”). Here’s another link to it: [edit]

Comment: Can't reproduce https://ideone.com/wNK4Lt

Comment: If the input is zero, you don't print anything